# Launch a program keeping focus on terminal

Tags: 12.04, command-line, bash

I'm making a script that combines taking input from the command line with the launch of other programs. So the script will go like this:

```
...
launch program
Read input from the terminal
...
```

The problem is that when I launch the program (even if I launch it in the background), the terminal looses focus and the launched program becomes active.

How do I launch a program keeping the focus on the terminal with a default Ubuntu command?

Thank you

Comment: Also you could try looking at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/80968/109543).

Comment: Interesting question, I don't think there is any way to guarantee that you won't lose focus.

Answer (score 3):

If you know the title of the terminal, you can switch back to it after opening the program using the [`wmctrl`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/wmctrl.1.html) command (it doesn't even look like the new program was in the foreground at all if the window opens instantly and you don't need the `sleep` command):

```
wmctrl -a <WIN-TITLE>
```

`<WIN-TITLE>` doesn't have to be the full title, for example, if the title was `TESTING`, `TEST` would work.

Depending on how long it takes to open the program, you might need to use the `sleep` command to delay the switch back to the terminal. You can use it like this: `sleep <SECONDS>s`.

To set the title of the terminal from within a script, use:

```
NAME="NEW_TITLE"; echo -en "\033]0;$NAME\a"
```

See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/31004/109543) for more information.

For example, here is a little script to open a program in the background:

```
NAME="Opening program..."; echo -en "\033]0;$NAME\a"
$1&
sleep 0.75s
wmctrl -a "Opening program"
```

Comment: I already saw that option but I was searching for a default ubuntu command, so there was no need for installing a new program

Comment: Sorry, it was already installed on my system so I didn't realize it wasn't installed by default.

Comment: It's OK, if no one gives a better answer in a week I'll mark this one as good. Thanks for the answer by the way

Comment: Three years have passed. Maybe it's time to mark the answer as good :)

Comment: 8 years and counting ... :D